# I'm trying to make a Harry Potter spell game

Tags: java, arrays

The player is supposed to input a spell from the series and if it is in the array, the computer will output a different spell in the array. If it is not inside the array, it will print the first spell in the array and so on.

I tested this with just 4 spells, but it always outputs "Crucio". I do not know why this is happening!
Please help.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class HarryPotterGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Harry Potter Spell Game!");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

            String[] Spells;
            Spells = new String[] {"Accio","AvadaKedavra","Crucio","Imperio"};

            System.out.println("Your turn. Do not use spaces!");
            Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
            String Spell1 = sn.nextLine(); 
            int i = 0;

            while(Spells[i] != Spell1){


                if (i == 4){
                    System.out.println("Accio");
                }
                i++;
            break;

            }

            System.out.println(Spells[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [equals method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare strings

```
while(!Spells[i].equals(Spell1)){
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` ( or `!=`) operator will not work as it will compare the references of the respective string in the memory. If they both strings are pointing to same location then only it will work.

So if you have 2 string

```
String s1 = "s1";
String s2 = "s1";
```

`s1 == s2`  will be `FALSE`

However if you have 2 strings references like

```
String s1 = "s1";
String s2 = s1;
```

`s1 == s2`  will be `TRUE`

Hence best way to compare two string is using equals() method. This will compare the content of the string.

Change your condition to

```
while(!Spells[i].equals(Spell1)){
```

to be more accurate use `equalsIgnoreCase()` for case sensitivity.

Best luck for your harry potter game. Hope there will be magic at your end soon!!!!

Comment: He-he. Believe or not both your examples will yield `true` :) It is because Java compiler allocates string constants pool so `s1` and `s2` will point to the same constant in pool. To make it `false` it must be `s1 = new String("s1"); s2 = new String("s1");` - in this case it will be two different objects